# Mock object and retain functionality of other methods

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Say for example I have this class:

```
class Foo {

    public function add($x, $y)
    {
        return $x + $y;
    }

    public function subtract($x, $y)
    {
        return $x - $y;
    }
}
```

and I wanted to change the behavior of the add method only:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Foo');
$mock->expects($this->once())->method('add')->will($this->returnCallback(function ($x, $y) {
    return ($x + 0) + ($y + 0);
}));

$this->assertEquals(4, $mock->add(2,2));
$this->assertEquals(2, $mock->subtract(4,2));
```

Why is my subtract method now returning null? I was expecting it to behave usual.

```
Failed asserting that null matches expected 2.
```

Comment: Can you add the code to the `mock()` method inside `class m` ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, i'm Using [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery).

Comment: @VladPreda I changed the code to the non-mockery one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
$mock = m::mock('Foo[add]');
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to do a partial mock specifying to getMock what method you want to mock:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Foo', array('add');
```

In this way only the add method is mocked, the rest of the object is behaving as usual.

Comment: Hi, both of you are correct but since aykut answered earlier I'm gonna choose his answer. Thanks for the help, I gave you an upvote too!

Comment: My answer for mockery verson of your question (before you edited) and @Ferca's answer is for PHPUnit's getMock method.